# Exception java.lang.NullPointerException accurs while trying to reach the service layer from my controller

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working with Spring STS (Also with Eclipse-juno, spring 3.1), and creating a spring template project.

My welcome page of the application is a simple form:

```
  <div id="editPresPage">
     <form action="editPresPage.do" method="post"> 
    <label>Enter Page Text</label><input type="text" name="page_text"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add New Page"/>
 </form>              
  </div>
```

When i deliver the form ,My controller comes into place:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {

    private Page_manager_service page_manager_service;

    public void setPage_manager_service(Page_manager_service page_manager_service) {
        this.page_manager_service = page_manager_service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/editPresPage",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView EditPresPage()    {
        page_manager_service.check();

        return new ModelAndView("thanks");      
    }
```

The controller needs to perform the check method (which is marked) from My Service Layer interface:

```
public interface Page_manager_service {
    public void check();
}
```

The Service Layer implementation:

```
public class Page_manager_service_mock_Impl implements Page_manager_service {

    public void check() {
        System.out.println("check method was done!!!");
    }
}
```

But i'll getting the following error while executing the check method:

***java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.topLevel.pack.HomeController.EditPresPage(HomeController.java:64)***

Here is my servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring  beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.topLevel.pack" />

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my root-context.xml (you can see that i wired the "page_manager_service" bean):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">    

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:annotation-config/> 

    <!--  Service Beans -->    
    <bean id="page_manager_service"  class="my.topLevel.pack.Services.Page_manager_service_mock_Impl">
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

I did not change anything in the web.xml file.

I can see that the service layer implementation is being injected because there is an "s" on it.

I'm able to transfer parameters from the view to the controller- so the problem isn't there.

It's in the controller<-> service layer communication.

I Don't know why i'm getting this error..

The problem was solved by doing this steps:

First step:Adding @Autowired to the page_manager_service field (It's ok to delete the setter).

Second step: In the root-context.xml file changing:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

to:

```
<context:component-scan 
    base-package="my.topLevel.pack">
</context:component-scan>
```

Third Step: Removing:

```
<bean id="page_manager_service"       class="my.topLevel.pack.Services.Page_manager_service_mock_Impl">
```

from root-context.xml.

Fourth Step:Adding @Component to Page_manager_service_mock_Impl

Comment: Ur Service bean has not been injected and its not available when the control comes to that point.Hence NullPointerException. I dont see where you have mapped the Service Bean to the controller Bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have created the `Page_manager_service` bean, it has not been injected into the `Controller` class, causing the `NPE` when you call

```
page_manager_service.check();
```

You could annotate `Page_manager_service` with `@Component` and *autowire* the `Controller`:

```
@Autowired
private Page_manager_service page_manager_service;
```

The setter will then be unnecessary ...

Side Note: Java uses camel-case which would make `page_manager_service` `pageManagerService`.

Comment: Before annotations we used to inject the beans by setter method. There is an appropriate setter method, why it is not injected?

Comment: The bean is created but never set/injected into the `Controller`. When using annotated Spring MVC, `autowiring` is cleaner to use as `Spring` creates the controllers...

Comment: he should have controller bean in the xml and it should have a property ref with service am i right?

Comment: You would almost _never_ do that. In fact the service bean should be annotated as a `@Service` (or `@Component`) and let `Spring` wire it up.